# How can I clean up this if-else function? (Javascript ES6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, refactoring, code-cleanup

I'm a beginner React developer.

I am cleaning up my codes.

I'm trying to get rid of the if-else statement as much as possible, but I don't know how to handle this function.

```
    const calc = () => {
        if (100 < responsiveWidth.phone) {
            setPerPage(1);
        } else if (100 < responsiveWidth.tablet) {
            setPerPage(2);
        } else if (100 < responsiveWidth.smallDesktop) {
            setPerPage(3);
        } else if (100 < responsiveWidth.desktop) {
            setPerPage(4);
        } else {
            setPerPage(6);
        }
    };
```

I really hate this code.
Can you help me out?

Comment: does it work? what about `width`? is it a number **and** an object at the same time?

Comment: What do you "hate" about this code? It is very straightforward, clear, and easy to understand.

Comment: Why do you need all those `Number()` calls?

Comment: I revised the question. It was a typo. I'm sorry.

Comment: What I don't like is poor readability and I don't want to write repeated codes.

Comment: Wait, where does the `100` come from? Put that in a constant, and it's much less repetitive already.

Comment: Oh, I forgot! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the index ([`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)) and add one.

```
const 
    widths = [width.phone, width.tablet, width.smallDesktop, width.desktop],
    calc = width => setPerPage(widths.findIndex(w => width < w) + 1) || 6);
```

Comment: I probably would do `[width.phone, width.table, width.smallDesktop, width.desktop, width.desktop, Infinity]` instead of that `|| 6`. Maybe even start the array with `0` (or `-Infinitiy`) and drop the `+1`.

Comment: I revised the question. It was a typo. I'm sorry. Can you look at the code of the question again?

Comment: You've been a great help. I will study more about ES6. Thank you so much.